# How can I convert this matlab code to python?

Tags: python, matlab

I have a Matlab code implementing a for loop which I have to convert it to python code:

```
for i = 1:numel(file_list)
    filename = file_list(i).name;
```

File_list consists of 207 CSV files having 3036*190 items. this is how the following part of the code looks like:

```
for i = 1:numel(file_list)
    filename = file_list(i).name;
    SS= strcat(filename);
    ActualRadarData = csvread(SS);
    RadarData = real(ActualRadarData(:,20:end));
```

and this is what I attempted in doing so which is not correct:

```
for i in 1:len(file_list):
     filename = os.path.basename('/path/file_list')
```

This method doesn't work out. how can it be done correctly?

Comment: How is `file_list` defined, in both your MATLAB and Python code?\

Comment: In Matlab code file_list is directory of csv files whereas in python code file_list is a dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Python starts indexes at zero, unlike MATLAB which starts indexing at 1, so you should keep that in mind. If you want to iterate through a list, you'd usually do `for element in list`, although you could iterate through indexes as well.

```
import os
for file in file_list:
    filename = os.path.basename(file)
```

I would recommend looking into a guide for indexing and looping in Python, and then for CSV reading I recommend using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast! however, i'm getting an error which says " 'dataframe' has no attribute 'rfind' "

Comment: Oh, is `file` a DataFrame? Maybe you could add an example of the format of `file_list` and `file` to your post.